# how to replace whole text in file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

i need to delete from file root certs and keys but can't seem to be able to do it with sed properly.

the file is something like this :

```
here
there


<ca>
sdasd
dasda
</ca>
<cert>
asasda
asa
</cert>
<key>
asdadsas
</key>
```

I need to delete everything from ca to key

Comment: Let us know what is your desired output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945621/using-sed-to-remove-a-block-of-text

Comment: that's the one , thx !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete from `<ca>` to `</cert>`, you will either need to escape the `/` inside `</cert>`

```
sed '/<ca>/,/<\/cert>/d' file
```

or use an alternate delimiter e.g.

```
sed '\#<ca>#,\#</cert>#d' file
```

Ex.

```
$ sed '\#<ca>#,\#</cert>#d' yourfile
here
there


<key>
asdadsas
</key>
```

In either case, add the `-i` or `--in-place` option to edit the file in place.

Comment: you rock , thx :)

Answer (score 2):

`perl` can do multiline matching with `-0`

```
perl -0pe 's/\n\<ca\>(.*\n)*?\<\/key\>//' file
```

add `-i` to edit the file in place.